# Why does a motor draw more current stopped or under load?

Tags: electric-current

I have a small motor connected to DC source, and use the ampere meter to survey the current through the motor. While the motor is rotating, I hold the motor by hand so that it stop. I see the current through the motor increases. Could you help me explain this problem?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationship between current through a motor and it's load](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51332/)

Answer (score 0):

When you are forcing the motor to stop by holding the motor by hand, you are actually applying a good amount of load which the motor is trying to overcome by trying to generate more power. Thus it draws more current.